# Echo the latest MySQL record in for loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I use PDO to connect the db and extract record from table's .

I want extract only latest Record but when I run following code don't echo anything ..

```
SELECT * FROM uds ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 1
```

my php code

```
<?php

            $params =null; //or any params
            $mrkfPDO =  new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=usd', 'root', '',
                array(
                    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
                    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"
                )
            );
            $mrkfStatement = $mrkfPDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM `uds` ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 1 ");
            $mrkfStatement->execute($params);
            $pays = $mrkfStatement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


            for($i=1; $i<count($pays); $i++) // see the change
            {

                $color = 'black';

                if($pays[$i]['price'] < $pays[($i-1)]['price'])
                    $color="red";
                elseif($pays[$i]['price'] > $pays[($i-1)]['price'])
                    $color = 'green';
                else
                    $color = 'black';

                echo "<tr>

                        <td>
                            <span style='color: $color'>"
                              .$pays[$i]['price'].
                            "</span>
                        </td>
                      </tr>";  
            }


            ?>
```

**Description code**:

With curl every 1 min go to the other website and get the USD price then insert in to the database ...

My db table have 2 field .... id (AUTO_INCREMENT) $ price ..

In top code:

If new price = latest price echo the number with back color.

and

If new price > latest price echo the number with green color.

and

If new price < latest price echo the number with red color.

Now. with foreach echo all records . I want only latest record (2000)...

Table

```
id | price
1  | 2300
2  | 2300 
3  | 2301  
4  | 2290
5  | 2000
```

Comment: If only one record no need for a loop.

Comment: how can only echo without loop?

Comment: Not sure what you mean there, `echo 'hi';`.

Comment: I want only echo latest record id 5 = 2000 no all records

Comment: `5 = 2000` doesn't make sense. Do you mean you want the 5 highest ids in your table?

Comment: No I dont want echo highest ... because I want if 2000 lower of 2290 echo with color red and if higher than 2290 echo with green color ... I wrote in top cod condition for this.

Comment: I don't know what you mean but with `LIMIT 1` in your query you are only requesting one record so the loop is pointless and `$pays[($i-1)]` is never going to exist.

Comment: How can echo without loop?

Comment: You said that exact comment and I replied already to it. Pretty basic stuff, http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the latest price, not the highest price, you should order by (I am assuming here) autoincrementing `id`:

```
select * from uds order by id desc limit 1
```

If you want to compare two latest prices, use `limit 2` instead of `limit 1`. Then you can just request the latest price in `$pays` with the index `0` and the previous latest price with index `1` (as records were sorted in the descending order).

Comment: When $i=0 echo Undefined offset: -1  in for($i=0; $i<count($pays); $i++)

Comment: You mean I don't understand.. Please write the code

Comment: @ERROR_404: You have all the code you need, just use the query and recommendations from my answer.

Comment: I modifies my code to this but echo  Undefined index: price////// $color = $color = 'black';
 
                if($pays ['price'] < 0)
                    $color="red";
                elseif($pays ['price'] > 0)
                    $color = 'green';
                else
                    $color = 'black';
 
                echo "<tr>
                         
                        <td>
                            <span style='color: $color'>"
                              .$pays ['price'].
                            "</span>
                        </td>
                      </tr>";

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL-Statement is almost correct but you order by the price not by the "time the row was inserted" or in other words the ID. Change it to:

```
  select * from uds order by id desc limit 1
```

So you get only the latest inserted row as you want for your comparison. So the `count()` of your result is `1`. This shows another mistake in your code. Following this the following code line will never come true:

```
`for($i=1; $i<count($pays); $i++)`
```

as `1 < 1` will never be true. Change it to

```
if(!empty($pays)) {
  $color = 'black';
  if($pays['price']) {
  // ...
} else {
  echo "No data row fetched";
}
```

So you check if you get a record back from the database and if yes you use this record.